# Share a class between the renderer and the main script in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, class, electron

I recently started a project on ElectronJS to organize competitions.

So I implemented classes to help me : `Competition`, `Pool`, ... And I would like to make them accessible to the renderer (the script associated with the HTML that will make the data visible) and to the main process as well (that will change the state of the competitions for example).

But the problem is :

- From the main process I can do `const {Competition} = require('path-to-my-class')` and it works
- But from the renderer, I’ve been doing `const {Competition} = require('path-to-my-class')` and it doesn’t work because I should be doing `import {Competition} from './path-to-my-class` which is not compatible with `module.exports`.

I did activate `require` in the renderer to get the `electron` `ipc`, for example, but I read that for the "home-made" modules you had to use `import` and `export`.

If you have a solution? Thank you in advance!

My config for the windows :

```js
function createMainWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1080,
        height: 720,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
        },
    });

    [...]
}
```

Error from the renderer :

```
Cannot find module 'path-to-my-class'
Require stack:
- path-to-my-html-file
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1054:15)
    at o._resolveFilename (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:2:3879)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:900:27)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
    at o._load (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:2:3109)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at my-js-script
```

I searched on google and found that it was very hard and a more like a DIY fix than a real fix. I don't know if there's a prettier way to do it.

I saw [someone asking the same question as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313823/how-to-share-class-definitions-between-electrons-main-and-renderer-process) two years ago, so I'm trying to rephrase it hoping it will help to respond.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have the main process use ESM? Via `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` or similar? (Sorry, I haven't tried Electron yet, but I know the main process is a Node.js process, and Node.js supports ESM...)

Comment: I just tried @T.J.Crowder with the following code : `import electron from "electron";` . Just that crashes with the error `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ... electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js not supported.`, seems impossible :(

Comment: That's too bad. :-( They'll get there eventually...

Comment: I'll try to see if I can propose a way to do it in the Electron source code itself, but with my current experience it will be hard o-o

Comment: I think it is definitely possible to have the main process use ESM.